# Is there any way in which we can open multiple get xmlhttprequests for multiple <li> tags when clicked on them?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here I was trying to get xmlhttprequest for 10 countries news headlines by just changing the source="countrycode" in the newsApi. I declared 10 `<li>` tags for 10 countries and gave them each an onclick function which calls a js function in which i appended the countrycode to the api. But its not working.
I checked the API is working fine. I also checked the single call for api if i give any countrycode (eg "br" for brazil) is working fine. But its not working inside a function.
What am I doing wrong ?

[ I have changed my API Key in the code for privacy issues ]

```js
function requestXml(str) {
  let source = str.value;
  // console.log(str);
  // console.log(source);
  // e.preventDefault();
  let apiKey = 'something';

  // Grab the news container
  let newsAccordion = document.getElementById('newsAccordion');

  // Create an ajax get request
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', `http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${source}&apiKey=${apiKey}`, true);

  // What to do when response is ready
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      let articles = json.articles;
      console.log(articles);
      let newsHtml = "";
      articles.forEach(function(element, index) {
        // console.log(element, index)
        let news = `<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="heading${index}">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${index}"
              aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                <b>Breaking News ${index + 1}:</b> ${element["title"]}
              </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse${index}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" 
          data-parent="#newsAccordion">
            <div class="card-body"> ${element["content"]}. 
              <a href="${element['url']}" target="_blank" >Read more here</a>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;
        newsHtml += news;
      });
      newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;
    } else {
      console.log("Some error occured")
    }
  }

  xhr.send();

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="br" value="br" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">Brazil</a></li>
        <li id="ca" value="ca" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">Canada</a></li>
        <li id="cn" value="cn" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">China</a></li>
        <li id="fr" value="fr" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">France</a></li>
        <li id="de" value="de" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">Germany</a></li>
        <li id="in" value="in" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">India</a></li>
        <li id="it" value="it" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">Italy</a></li>
        <li id="jp" value="jp" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">Japan</a></li>
        <li id="gb" value="gb" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">United Kingdom</a></li>
        <li id="us" value="us" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a href="">United States</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      <div class="container my-3">
        <h3>Top News <span class="badge badge-secondary">by Indian shatabdi News</span></h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="accordion" id="newsAccordion"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does not work? Errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues

- LIs do not have `value` only form fields have that
- You click the link, not the LI
- No need for a link if you just want to click on something
- You are using http instead https

NOTE the code below does not run without a valid api key but as you can see it is calling it

```js
function requestXml(source) {
  let apiKey = 'some key';

  // Grab the news container
  let newsAccordion = document.getElementById('newsAccordion');

  // Create an ajax get request
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${source}&apiKey=${apiKey}`, true);

  // What to do when response is ready
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      let articles = json.articles;
      console.log(articles);
      let newsHtml = "";
      articles.forEach(function(element, index) {
        // console.log(element, index)
        let news = `<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="heading${index}">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${index}"
              aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                <b>Breaking News ${index + 1}:</b> ${element["title"]}
              </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse${index}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" 
          data-parent="#newsAccordion">
            <div class="card-body"> ${element["content"]}. 
              <a href="${element['url']}" target="_blank" >Read more here</a>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;
        newsHtml += news;
      });
      newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;
    } else {
      console.log("Some error occured")
    }
  }

  xhr.send();

}

document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const cc = tgt.dataset.cc;
  requestXml(cc)
})
```

```css
#list li { cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" id="list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="br" data-cc="br">Brazil</li>
        <li id="ca" data-cc="ca">Canada</li>
        <li id="cn" data-cc="cn">China</li>
        <li id="fr" data-cc="fr">France</li>
        <li id="de" data-cc="de">Germany</li>
        <li id="in" data-cc="in">India</li>
        <li id="it" data-cc="it">Italy</li>
        <li id="jp" data-cc="jp">Japan</li>
        <li id="gb" data-cc="gb">United Kingdom</li>
        <li id="us" data-cc="us">United States</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      <div class="container my-3">
        <h3>Top News <span class="badge badge-secondary">by Indian shatabdi News</span></h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="accordion" id="newsAccordion"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example when code is running to test the parsing logic

NOTE There are  \r\n in the string I had to double escape

```js
function show(jsonStr) {
  let obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  let articles = obj.articles;
//  console.log(articles);
  let newsHtml = "";
  articles.forEach(function(element, index) {
    // console.log(element, index)
    let news = `<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="heading${index}">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${index}"
              aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                <b>Breaking News ${index + 1}:</b> ${element["title"]}
              </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse${index}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" 
          data-parent="#newsAccordion">
            <div class="card-body"> ${element["content"]}. 
              <a href="${element['url']}" target="_blank" >Read more here</a>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;
    newsHtml += news;
  });
  newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;

}
const json = `{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 34,
"articles": [
{
"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Le 10 Sport"
},
"author": "G.d.S.S.",
"title": "Mercato - PSG : Le prochain club de Tuchel devrait être… - Le 10 Sport",
"description": "En fin de contrat en juin prochain avec le PSG, Thomas Tuchel ne devrait pas être prolongé par le club de la capitale. Et Manchester United semble bien parti pour relancer le technicien allemand cet…",
"url": "https://le10sport.com/football/mercato/mercato-psg-le-prochain-club-de-tuchel-devrait-etre-530383",
"urlToImage": "https://le10static.com/img/master/0000/0018/180166.jpeg",
"publishedAt": "2020-12-21T01:00:00Z",
"content": "Publié le 21 décembre 2020 à 2h00 par G.d.S.S. En fin de contrat en juin prochain avec le PSG, Thomas Tuchel ne devrait pas être prolongé par le club de la capitale. Et Manchester United semble bien … [+993 chars]"
},
{
"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Foot Mercato"
},
"author": "Alexis Pereira",
"title": "Christophe Galtier rend hommage au jardinier disparu au Moustoir - Foot Mercato",
"description": "",
"url": "https://www.footmercato.net/a4286436182457181763-christophe-galtier-rend-hommage-au-jardinier-disparu-au-moustoir",
"urlToImage": "https://assets-fr.imgfoot.com/media/cache/1200x675/galtier-losc-2020.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2020-12-21T00:25:38Z",
"content": "La suite après cette publicité\\r\\nAu sortir du revers du FC Lorient face au Stade Rennais ce dimanche après-midi (0-3, 16e journée de Ligue 1), un terrible accident s'est produit sur la pelouse du Stad… [+238 chars]"
}
]
}`


show(json)
```

```css
#list li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" id="list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="br" data-cc="br">Brazil</li>
        <li id="ca" data-cc="ca">Canada</li>
        <li id="cn" data-cc="cn">China</li>
        <li id="fr" data-cc="fr">France</li>
        <li id="de" data-cc="de">Germany</li>
        <li id="in" data-cc="in">India</li>
        <li id="it" data-cc="it">Italy</li>
        <li id="jp" data-cc="jp">Japan</li>
        <li id="gb" data-cc="gb">United Kingdom</li>
        <li id="us" data-cc="us">United States</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      <div class="container my-3">
        <h3>Top News <span class="badge badge-secondary">by Indian shatabdi News</span></h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="accordion" id="newsAccordion"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function requestXml(str) {
  let source = str.children[0].innerHTML;
  console.log(source);
  let apiKey = 'something';

  // Grab the news container
  let newsAccordion = document.getElementById('newsAccordion');

  // Create an ajax get request
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', `http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${source}&apiKey=${apiKey}`, true);

  // What to do when response is ready
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      let articles = json.articles;
      console.log(articles);
      let newsHtml = "";
      articles.forEach(function(element, index) {
        // console.log(element, index)
        let news = `<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="heading${index}">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${index}"
              aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                <b>Breaking News ${index + 1}:</b> ${element["title"]}
              </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse${index}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" 
          data-parent="#newsAccordion">
            <div class="card-body"> ${element["content"]}. 
              <a href="${element['url']}" target="_blank" >Read more here</a>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;
        newsHtml += news;
      });
      newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;
    } else {
      console.log("Some error occured")
    }
  }

  xhr.send();

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="br" value="br" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>Brazil</a></li>
        <li id="ca" value="ca" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>Canada</a></li>
        <li id="cn" value="cn" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>China</a></li>
        <li id="fr" value="fr" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>France</a></li>
        <li id="de" value="de" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>Germany</a></li>
        <li id="in" value="in" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>India</a></li>
        <li id="it" value="it" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>Italy</a></li>
        <li id="jp" value="jp" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>Japan</a></li>
        <li id="gb" value="gb" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>United Kingdom</a></li>
        <li id="us" value="us" onclick="requestXml(this)"><a>United States</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      <div class="container my-3">
        <h3>Top News <span class="badge badge-secondary">by Indian shatabdi News</span></h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="accordion" id="newsAccordion"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is OP using "${...}" ? And where is JSX relevant? Is your answer actually meant to be for this question?

Comment: 1. You still have the invalid value attribute. 2. You wrap the name in A tag, but do not give a href which makes the A tag a completely irrelevant noise since it does not even give the pointer. 3. The API needs the two letter code and not the name of the country. The question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65388483/295783)